# How can I trigger calling a method on an object in my view from within the viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

My WPF application has a tool bar that contains several buttons that by default do not have any command bindings. Within the application various different forms/windows can be opened (think MDI) and each of these views is responsible for registering any of its commands with a shared utility that will apply them to the tool bar buttons.

The toolbar and other standard ui pieces reside in a separate library from the views and the shared utility I mentioned is the only interface for views to hook into the buttons. Here is an example usage of how the view registers a command

```
public class MyView : BaseView 
{
    public MyView(CommandHolder commandHolder) : base(commandHolder)
    {
        SaveCommand = new DelegateCommand(Save,CanSave);

        //RegisterCommand is a method on BaseView that works with the commandHolder object
        RegisterCommand(DefaultCommands.SaveCommand, SaveCommand);
    }
}
```

This functionality is working great for all back end tasks, like saving and searchign, but now I find that I need to be able to trigger functionality that exists within the view from one of these commands.

The specific example here is I have an Export to Excel button in my toolbar that I want to of course generate a xlsx file based on data in a grid.

I am using DevExpress controls and their grid supports the following method call:

```
//taken from xaml code behind
 grid.ExportToXlsx(@"c:\grid_export.xlsx");
```

Is there any way for my command execute method to be able to trigger this call short of giving the viewmodel a reference to the view?

Comment: If all your command would do is call that method then there is no point making a command in the ViewModel, a click event handler in the code-behind will do just fine. If you have your heart set on a ViewModel command then you could use event/messaging patterns like Prism EventAggregator.

Comment: The problem with that is what I tried to explain in the first part, the button itself is enitrely separate from thew view where this method needs to be called, a command is literally the only option

Comment: @GlenThomas I've added a bit more explanation that hopefully clears that up

Comment: I think I see how it works. Your toolbar control can apply to any window, depending on which one is active. Sounds like some sort of event based pattern would be good. Are you using any MVVM frameworks like Prism, MVVM Light, Caliburn, etc.

Comment: I'm using a combination of Prism and DevExpress' Mvvm library, The toolbar is a DevExpress RibbonToolbar and I've also used the IActiveAware interface for the commands that get registered in the tool bar.

Comment: @Phaeze you can then use the Prism event aggregator. Have the view subscribe to an event (e.g. ExportGridEvent) and have the command invoked by the toolbar raise this event.

Comment: @user469104 Haha now I feel silly, I'm actually using SharpMediator to do exactly that type of thing elsewhere in the application. For some reason my brain didn't realize I could just pass that to the view.

Comment: Well if either of you think this will be helpful to future users go ahead and post an answer, otherwise I may just delete this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prism has an EventAggregator component for loosely coupled communication between components in your application.

Create a class that inherits from `CompositePresentationEvent`. The generic type is the type of any data you want to use as a payload

```
public class ExportRequestedEvent : CompositePresentationEvent<object> { }
```

Create an event aggregator using the Singleton pattern or your IoC container of choice so that the instance is shared across relevant components.

```
IEventAggregator _aggregator = new EventAggregator();
```

In the command use the event aggregator to get the event and publish

```
_aggregator.GetEvent<ExportRequestedEvent>().Publish(null);
```

In your view you can register a method to handle the event using the Subscribe method

```
_aggregator.GetEvent<ExportRequestedEvent>().Subscribe(Export);

private void Export()
{
    grid.ExportToXlsx(@"c:\grid_export.xlsx");
}
```

You can add your own functionality to the views to determine which one is currently active and should act on the event.